# How to create a panel tab?

Tags: html, css, tabs, panel

is there anyone here who knows how to create a panel tab?it wasn't discussed in our class and i was asked by my boss to change my list link of A to Z to a panel tab. my link list is working properly. i tried making the letters in my links (you will see later) an image, but my boss doesn't want it that way,he specifically said that for example, you clicked the link letter "A", the link should look like it merged with the table or as if data's when links a clicked are like in different pages.

here is the code i used for my linked letters:
*noticed that A and B link are different, that was my first attempt that he did not like.

```
    <table class="sub" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">              
            <!--A - Z link page-->
                <tr>
                <td colspan ="6" align="CENTER">
                <a href="index.php?namelist=a"onmouseover="AmouseOver()" onmouseout="AmouseOut()" /><img src="images/A.png" id="A" /></a>
                &nbsp;
                <a href="index.php?namelist=b"onmouseover="BmouseOver()" onmouseout="BmouseOut()" /><img src="images/B.png" id="B" /></a>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href="index.php?namelist=c">C</a>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href="index.php?namelist=d">D</a>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href="index.php?namelist=e">E</a>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href="index.php?namelist=f">F</a>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href="index.php?namelist=g">G</a>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href="index.php?namelist=h">H</a>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href="index.php?namelist=i">I</a>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href="index.php?namelist=j">J</a>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href="index.php?namelist=k">K</a>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href="index.php?namelist=l">L</a>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href="index.php?namelist=m">M</a>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href="index.php?namelist=n">N</a>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href="index.php?namelist=o">O</a>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href="index.php?namelist=p">P</a>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href="index.php?namelist=q">Q</a>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href="index.php?namelist=r">R</a>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href="index.php?namelist=s">S</a>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href="index.php?namelist=t">T</a>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href="index.php?namelist=u">U</a>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href="index.php?namelist=v">V</a>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href="index.php?namelist=w">W</a>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href="index.php?namelist=x">X</a>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href="index.php?namelist=y">Y</a>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href="index.php?namelist=z">Z</a>

                </td>
                </tr>
```

these set of codes will be called when the user clicks on the link. actually my codes are working perfectly. my boss would just like to change the design a bit just so that there is something that i could do in my on-the-job training. See im just a student but i am always given a hard time here. i hope someone could help me here

***MisaChan***

PS. i already tried searching sites on how to make panel tab without barely changing my codes but no luck found. almost all are code generators and i dont like the result in those sites, i think css will help me here also as said by most forums i've seen

Comment: What exactly is it that you want to do? Please be a bit more specific.

Comment: something like in the site here[link](http://www.softpedia.com)

Comment: but the text in mine should consist the letters A-Z and will use Grey and white color. the function of that part of my program is to output names and details of the registered employee in the company grouped by their first name, that is why the link is from A-Z sir @minitech

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the trick in making a tabbed panel is to change the style of your selected item different from the other tabs. You will definitely need to use CSS for this. I would change all of the letters into spans and give them a class name  like "tabunsel" and for the selected tab a class name like "tabsel".

In the CSS for the span you can then do some tricks like adding a background image that looks like a tab with different colours for the selected and unselected ones. You could also do this with pure CSS if you are up to the challenge.

I would start by studying a the code and CSS of a few good looking tabbed pages on the web or look for a tutorial. I found [this](http://blixt.org/articles/tabbed-navigation-using-css#section=introduction) just Googling.

Comment: @Rasika sir, i already created an image for the mouseover and mouseout, if that is how you call it. and i already put my <a>tags inside a <div>. but i am not that much familiar with css yet. but i'll try to read your link sir :)

Comment: You will need to read on CSS. This would be a good excuse for you to learn it. Start with the CSS tutorial on W3Schools http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp.

Comment: sir @Rasika, i already know some of the basic programming codes of css since w3schools.com became my professors study link :) i think i will try to study your first link then try attaching it with my program. after that, i will update you for the results or changes in my program :)

Comment: ok i got it!! i sure wish it would be ok in my program! thanks sir @Rasika! thats a really good source code :) and educational too :)

Comment: Thank the person who wrote the tutorial. I just found it via Google.

Comment: @MisaChan: its indeed have some good tutorial specially for beginner, and I also used it as my starting-ground before. But some of the tutorials are not correct at all. Why? see it here http://w3fools.com/

Comment: @ace, I intended the tutorial I mentioned in my post and not the W3C ones in my previous comment. I was also not aware of the fact that W3CSchools not affiliated with W3C. It is misleading indeed. +1 for the pointer.

Comment: sir @Rasika and sir @ace thanks again :) now i just have to put it inside my file :) wish me luck

Comment: @Rasika: I was also not aware before, until I saw it in a comment here in SO. And there's a lot of good practices we can learn here in SO.

Comment: @Rasika, one last question, may i put an <OL> inside a <td> you see since my A-Z list is in <td> ten inside, i will just put each <a> tag in a <li> tag?

Comment: You can do without the <td> when you are working with CSS. With CSS you can make any HTML tag look like a table cell. Also, you can make a list look like a list of tabs using CSS. It is up to you to explore.

Comment: @Rasika, my panel tags are working even if its inside a td(wherein it should really be there) but the my problem is the class="current" located in the li tag. you sir,all my links are located at the same file location which is the index.php, my A-Z links are called to the same php file by putting ?namelist="value" after the href index.php. so my only problem now is the current page.

Comment: user cant determine which page are they on since having 1 php file,my class="current" will only be put on the homepage. but when i clicked another file, the class="current" remains in the homepage link although the link clicked for example is "A" i hope you could help me with this one. i posted anoter question here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040537/fixing-current-tab-color-using-1-php-file-only)

Comment: As you are passing namelist to the page, you can read the GET parameter namelist to identify which page you are displaying. Assuming you are using PHP use $_GET['namelist'] to determine the current highlighted value. This part is off the question you have asked, so I suggest that you post it as a new question if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, not like that. Here's how I would do it:

```
<div id="tabs"><a href="index.php?namelist=a">A</a> <a href="index.php?namelist=b">B</a> <a href="index.php?namelist=c">C</a> <a href="index.php?namelist=d">D</a> <a href="index.php?namelist=e">E</a> <a href="index.php?namelist=f">F</a> <a href="index.php?namelist=g">G</a> <a href="index.php?namelist=h">H</a> <a href="index.php?namelist=i">I</a> <a href="index.php?namelist=j">J</a> <a href="index.php?namelist=k">K</a> <a href="index.php?namelist=l">L</a> <a href="index.php?namelist=m">M</a> <a href="index.php?namelist=n">N</a> <a href="index.php?namelist=o">O</a> <a href="index.php?namelist=p">P</a> <a href="index.php?namelist=q">Q</a> <a href="index.php?namelist=r">R</a> <a href="index.php?namelist=s">S</a> <a href="index.php?namelist=t">T</a> <a href="index.php?namelist=u">U</a> <a href="index.php?namelist=v">V</a> <a href="index.php?namelist=w">W</a> <a href="index.php?namelist=x">X</a> <a href="index.php?namelist=y">Y</a> <a href="index.php?namelist=z">Z</a></div>
```

Then, look at the CSS [here](http://squaredcode.comoj.com/) to get an idea of how you might implement tabs.

Comment: you mean i could use plain <a>tags and just put divs outside it?? i dont get the site you gave earlier, i cant find the css there