# Fixing Current Tab Color using 1 php file only

Tags: php, html

im sorry for the poor title, i dont know how to explain it. You see i have already created my panel tabs with the help of ***ol***, ***li*** and ***css***. it is working perfectly but then there is one problem that occured in the program. this tab **li class="current"**

the purpose of the ***class=current*** that is set in a specified link will help change the background image of the active link. the css code for that is already set and working. I will first show you the codes i used here:

```
<ol id="toc">
                <li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                <li class="current"><a href="index.php"><span>#</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="index.php?namelist=a"><span>A</span></a></li>          
                <li><a href="index.php?namelist=b"><span>B</span></a></li>              
                <li><a href="index.php?namelist=c"><span>C</span></a></li>      
                <li><a href="index.php?namelist=d"><span>D</span></a></li>          
                <li><a href="index.php?namelist=e"><span>E</span></a></li>          
                <li><a href="index.php?namelist=f"><span>F</span></a></li>          
                <li><a href="index.php?namelist=g"><span>G</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="index.php?namelist=h"><span>H</span></a></li>          
                <li><a href="index.php?namelist=i"><span>I</span></a></li>              
                <li><a href="index.php?namelist=j"><span>J</span></a></li>              
                <li><a href="index.php?namelist=k"><span>K</span></a></li>      
                <li><a href="index.php?namelist=l"><span>L</span></a></li>      
                <li><a href="index.php?namelist=m"><span>M</span></a></li>                  
                <li><a href="index.php?namelist=n"><span>N</span></a></li>      
                <li><a href="index.php?namelist=o"><span>O</span></a></li>          
                <li><a href="index.php?namelist=p"><span>P</span></a></li>          
                <li><a href="index.php?namelist=q"><span>Q</span></a></li>          
                <li><a href="index.php?namelist=r"><span>R</span></a></li>              
                <li><a href="index.php?namelist=s"><span>S</span></a></li>                  
                <li><a href="index.php?namelist=t"><span>T</span></a></li>          
                <li><a href="index.php?namelist=u"><span>U</span></a></li>              
                <li><a href="index.php?namelist=v"><span>V</span></a></li>  
                <li><a href="index.php?namelist=w"><span>W</span></a></li>          
                <li><a href="index.php?namelist=x"><span>X</span></a></li>          
                <li><a href="index.php?namelist=y"><span>Y</span></a></li>              
                <li><a href="index.php?namelist=z"><span>Z</span></a></li>
                </ol>
```

as you can see here is the list of links that i have. its purpose is to search the employee name and information from the database and output in on the next  tags where the name of the employee must start with the letter specified in the link list A-Z that were clicked.

now my problem is, the links are called to the same page and does not contain its own php file. from the site that was recommended on me to study, i saw that each linked have its own php file thus the only difference is the location on the **class=current** example:

**if your on A.php**

```
    <ol id="toc">
<li class="current"><a href="A.php"><span>A</span></a></li>         
<li><a href="B.php"><span>B</span></a></li>
</ol>
```

the link in that page contains the **class=current** but the other li tags does not, else when clicked on a different link like for example on B.php

```
<ol id="toc">
<li><a href="A.php"><span>A</span></a></li>         
<li class="current"><a href="B.php"><span>B</span></a></li>
</ol>
```

the class="current" is in link B.

but mine is called in the same page by inserting ?namelist=a in each link. if i put class="current" on every li link, i would be able to get what i want which is making it able to see your current page. does anyone here knows how?? thanks for those who will reply :)

MisaChan

Comment: it can be done by CSS and jQuery, but first please mention clearly that wat u exact want? AFA I understand that u want that on each page like `a.php` then tabwith name `a` shoud be active...is there 26 tabs??

Comment: no sir, i dont have any a.php,b.php and so on, all links are in the same php file index.php, the links above are just example of the things i learned,but i cannot apply it because i only have 1 php file (index.php) and the A-Z link are only called using the ?namelist="somevalue" after the href file. what i want is toshow your current page,like if you click A,the color should change to a different color,else when clicked B, link A returns to the default color and B now will have a darker background color

Comment: This is a duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041536/how-to-change-class-current-location-in-a-list/6041586#6041586. CV-pls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function will loop through a to z and check if the current page is index.php?namelist=a or b,c ect determining where to place the class="current"

```
function toc_menu($current){
    $return ='<ol id="toc">
                <li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</li>'."\n";
    $return .= ($current=='') ? '<li class="current"><a href="index.php"><span>#</span></a></li>'."\n" : '<li><a href="index.php"><span>#</span></a></li>'."\n";
    foreach(range('a','z') as $link){
        $return .= ($current==$link) ? '<li class="current"><a href="index.php?namelist='.$link.'"><span>'.strtoupper($link).'</span></a></li>'."\n" : '<li><a href="index.php?namelist='.$link.'"><span>'.strtoupper($link).'</span></a></li>'."\n";
    }
    $return .="</ol>\n";
    return $return;
}

//echo where you want the menu
echo toc_menu(strtolower($_REQUEST['namelist']));

//or hold it in a variable to display later on
$tocmenu = toc_menu(strtolower($_REQUEST['namelist']));
```

//outputs this is E was clicked

```
   <ol id="toc">
                <li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
<li><a href="index.php"><span>#</span></a></li>
<li><a href="index.php?namelist=a"><span>A</span></a></li>
<li><a href="index.php?namelist=b"><span>B</span></a></li>
<li><a href="index.php?namelist=c"><span>C</span></a></li>
<li><a href="index.php?namelist=d"><span>D</span></a></li>
<li class="current"><a href="index.php?namelist=e"><span>E</span></a></li>
<li><a href="index.php?namelist=f"><span>F</span></a></li>

<li><a href="index.php?namelist=g"><span>G</span></a></li>
<li><a href="index.php?namelist=h"><span>H</span></a></li>
<li><a href="index.php?namelist=i"><span>I</span></a></li>
<li><a href="index.php?namelist=j"><span>J</span></a></li>
<li><a href="index.php?namelist=k"><span>K</span></a></li>
<li><a href="index.php?namelist=l"><span>L</span></a></li>
<li><a href="index.php?namelist=m"><span>M</span></a></li>
<li><a href="index.php?namelist=n"><span>N</span></a></li>
<li><a href="index.php?namelist=o"><span>O</span></a></li>

<li><a href="index.php?namelist=p"><span>P</span></a></li>
<li><a href="index.php?namelist=q"><span>Q</span></a></li>
<li><a href="index.php?namelist=r"><span>R</span></a></li>
<li><a href="index.php?namelist=s"><span>S</span></a></li>
<li><a href="index.php?namelist=t"><span>T</span></a></li>
<li><a href="index.php?namelist=u"><span>U</span></a></li>
<li><a href="index.php?namelist=v"><span>V</span></a></li>
<li><a href="index.php?namelist=w"><span>W</span></a></li>
<li><a href="index.php?namelist=x"><span>X</span></a></li>

<li><a href="index.php?namelist=y"><span>Y</span></a></li>
<li><a href="index.php?namelist=z"><span>Z</span></a></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: how do you do that and where whould i put it?? sorry sir @Lawrence, im still a rookie and i just recently learned how to make a panel tab.

Comment: i dont have A-Z.php, my A-Z link is also located in my index.php as well. i just named it individual using ?namelist after the href link

Comment: @Lawrence i tried your post sir but it did not echoed my A-Z list, where should i put the  RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^([A-Z]).php$ index.php?namelist=$1,,,, and do i still have to write the output in your post?

Comment: the mod_rewrite goes in a file called .htaccess on your server, the function goes in your index.php file and will loop through A to Z. change the <a href="'.$link.'.php"> to  <a href="index.php?namelist='.$link.'"> in the function if you dont want to use .htaccess the solution to your question is the usage of finding the current page from $_REQUEST['namelist'] there are lots of ways to output your desired result, but a loop & check is best

Comment: @Lawrence, is there other ways that will not require to change the .htaccess?

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone, i already saw what causes the error :) i put ?namelist=% after index.php in the # link. and now its working :) thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want a different color of the link on the current page. For e.g. if someone goes to index.php?namelist=a, the color for link A should be different than others. If this is the case, then just add a check for $_REQUEST['namelist'] while adding the class and you should be okay.

Comment: i already had my css made for class=current, that will already trigger the color change when the link is clicked. and what do you mean add $_REQUEST['namelist']?? where should i put it?