# How to change class="current" location in a list?

Tags: php, html

im sorry for the poor title, i dont know how to explain it. You see i have already created my panel tabs with the help of `<ol>`, `<li>` and css. it is working perfectly but then there is one problem that occured in the program. this tab **`<li class="current">`**

the purpose of the ***class=current*** that is set in a specified link will help change the background image of the active link. the css code for that is already set and working. I will first show you the codes i used here:

```
<ol id="toc">
                <li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                <li class="current"><a href="index.php"><span>#</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="index.php?namelist=a"><span>A</span></a></li>          
                <li><a href="index.php?namelist=b"><span>B</span></a></li>              
                <li><a href="index.php?namelist=c"><span>C</span></a></li>      
                <li><a href="index.php?namelist=d"><span>D</span></a></li>          
                <li><a href="index.php?namelist=e"><span>E</span></a></li>          
                <li><a href="index.php?namelist=f"><span>F</span></a></li>          
                <li><a href="index.php?namelist=g"><span>G</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="index.php?namelist=h"><span>H</span></a></li>          
                <li><a href="index.php?namelist=i"><span>I</span></a></li>              
                <li><a href="index.php?namelist=j"><span>J</span></a></li>              
                <li><a href="index.php?namelist=k"><span>K</span></a></li>      
                <li><a href="index.php?namelist=l"><span>L</span></a></li>      
                <li><a href="index.php?namelist=m"><span>M</span></a></li>                  
                <li><a href="index.php?namelist=n"><span>N</span></a></li>      
                <li><a href="index.php?namelist=o"><span>O</span></a></li>          
                <li><a href="index.php?namelist=p"><span>P</span></a></li>          
                <li><a href="index.php?namelist=q"><span>Q</span></a></li>          
                <li><a href="index.php?namelist=r"><span>R</span></a></li>              
                <li><a href="index.php?namelist=s"><span>S</span></a></li>                  
                <li><a href="index.php?namelist=t"><span>T</span></a></li>          
                <li><a href="index.php?namelist=u"><span>U</span></a></li>              
                <li><a href="index.php?namelist=v"><span>V</span></a></li>  
                <li><a href="index.php?namelist=w"><span>W</span></a></li>          
                <li><a href="index.php?namelist=x"><span>X</span></a></li>          
                <li><a href="index.php?namelist=y"><span>Y</span></a></li>              
                <li><a href="index.php?namelist=z"><span>Z</span></a></li>
                </ol>
```

as you can see here is the list of links that i have. its purpose is to search the employee name and information from the database and output in on the next `<tr><td>` tags where the name of the employee must start with the letter specified in the link list A-Z that were clicked.

now my problem is, the links are called to the same page and does not contain its own php file. from the site that was recommended on me to study, i saw that each linked have its own php file thus the only difference is the location on the **class=current** example:

**if your on A.php**

```
    <ol id="toc">
<li class="current"><a href="A.php"><span>A</span></a></li>         
<li><a href="B.php"><span>B</span></a></li>
</ol>
```

the link in that page contains the **class=current** but the other li tags does not, else when clicked on a different link like for example on B.php

```
<ol id="toc">
<li><a href="A.php"><span>A</span></a></li>         
<li class="current"><a href="B.php"><span>B</span></a></li>
</ol>
```

the class="current" is in link B.

****NOTE this 2 sets of codes are not what i want. its an example of what i have learned.***

but my links **does not** contain its own php file. all of the links are located in the index.php and are called using the **?namelist="somevalue"** inserted before the href **"index.php"**.

what i want for it to happen is on how to change the ***class="current"*** location in a certain href whenever the link is clicked. does anyone here knows how to do that that will not require to change the htaccess?? thanks for those who will reply :)

MisaChan

Comment: did you try my example of your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040600/fixing-current-tab-color-using-1-php-file-only

Comment: yes i did sir @Lawrence, but it did not echoed anything. you said the something about htaccess, but i was trying to avoid changing it. Do you know other ways besides having to change my htaccess for your codes to work? i was told yours will really work but i was told that the htaccess must not be changed so im finding other alternatives :(

Comment: put the function in my answer in your index.php and where ever you want the menu put echo toc_menu(strtolower($_REQUEST['namelist']));
simple....

Comment: sir @Lawrence, it finally output the A-Z list, but there was an error in your **echo toc_menu(strtolower($_REQUEST['namelist']));
** and **$tocmenu = toc_menu(strtolower($_REQUEST['namelist']));
** >>>it states **Notice: Undefined index: namelist in C:\wamp\www\gmdc\index.php on line 319/322** which is the location of the 2

Answer (score 1):

Do it manually:

```
class="<?php echo ($_GET['namelist'] == 'a' ? 'current' : NULL); ?>"
class="<?php echo ($_GET['namelist'] == 'b' ? 'current' : NULL); ?>"
class="<?php echo ($_GET['namelist'] == 'c' ? 'current' : NULL); ?>"
class="<?php echo ($_GET['namelist'] == 'd' ? 'current' : NULL); ?>"
```

Or do it intelligently:

```
<?php
foreach (range('a', 'z') as $letter) {
?>
<li class="<?php echo ($_GET['namelist'] == $letter ? 'current' : NULL); ?>"><a href="index.php"><span>#</span></a></li>
<? } ?>
```

Comment: why not use foreach(range('a','z') as $letter){}

Comment: Just spotted your answer - cheers... completely forgot about that.

Comment: I'd just suggest you echo out the whole line, rather than closing and re-opening PHP blocks. Every time you do a <?php there's a fair bit of overhead associated with it.

Comment: @mjec - you've got a fair point, but for the sake of the front end developers, I usually try and separate PHP & HTML as much as possible for their ease of access - regardless of the overhead. I don't much like working in quotes either ;).